# Convert Google Sheets to XLSX

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having issues trying to convert gsheet to xlsx. The code below converts gsheet to gdoc but I'm not sure how to convert to xlsx. I know it's something to do with the MimeType() property but I'm sure how to change the statement so that it can convert gsheet to xlsx. Any help would be great.

```
function convertToExcel() {
  // Google Sheets file
  var spreadsheetId = '1xlF...m6SE';

  // Open the gsheet file
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);

  // Make excelFile grab file ID
  var excelFile = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId())

  // Convert the copied file to xlsx (currently not working)
  var newFile = Drive.Files.insert(
    { title: excelFile.getName(), mimeType: excelFile.getMimeType() },
    excelFile.getBlob()
  );

  // Send original file to trash
  //excelFile.setTrashed(true);

  // URL log of the new file
  Logger.log('Excel file created: ' + newFile.alternateLink);
}
```